# TensorFlow: Read batch features to an array

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tf.contrib.learn.ReadBatchFeatures` (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/input_processing#read_batch_features) to read in `Example` protos as part of my input function, which returns a dict of `Tensor` objects. After training my model, calling `predict` on my `Estimator` returns one batch of predictions as an array, which I would like to compare to the known values.

I try to obtain the known values by calling `tf.Session().run(labels)`, where `labels` is a `Tensor` of known values, returned from the input function. However, at this point, my program hangs. I suspect it is stuck in an infinite loop reading labels from the disk, rather than just reading one batch as I would like.

Is this the correct way to obtain one batch of values in the `labels` `Tensor`?

Edit: I have tried to start the queue runners, is the following correct?

```
_, labels = eval_input_fn()
with tf.Session().as_default():
  tf.local_variables_initializer()
  tf.train.start_queue_runners()
  label_values = labels.eval()
print(label_values)
```

Comment: maybe you didn't start queue runners and your queue is empty? Reads from empty queue hang

Comment: Thanks, I remember now that the documentation mentions this, but I forgot about it. My session still hangs though, can you tell what's wrong?

Comment: Add timeout to see what operation is hanging, something like `config = tf.ConfigProto();
config.operation_timeout_in_ms=60000;
sess= tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)`

Answer (score 2):

The whole setup you need is:

```
_, labels = eval_input_fn()

with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([
            tf.local_variables_initializer(),
            tf.global_variables_initializer()
        ])

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                print(sess.run(label))

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as error:
            coord.request_stop(error)
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```